# Split Geometry into Instances (Geometry Nodes)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a point cloud with lots of points.
[image]
Now I want to split up this point cloud into groups of 8, so that I can manipulate these groups individually (e.g. rotate them as a group).

I can kind of achieve this with the "Separate Geometry" node:
[image]
However, that is not feasible with more points, if I want to split the geometry into hundreds of groups / instances).

Is there any way to split geometry into a lot of parts (not just two like "Separate Geometry" does)?

Comment: How do you want to identify the groups?.. (what would you like the interface to be to do that)

Comment: @RobinBetts In my case, I just want the first 8, the second 8 ... in the order as they are stored. However, in general it could also be all points that share the same value of some named attribute.

Comment: [Geometry Nodes: new Split to Instances node](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/commit/5bee6bcedc86b7f8fa2d451186eff75a721bd62d). Blender 4.1 apparently will bring a node that serves this exact purpose.

Comment: @Hulifier That's great news! It's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **Blender 4.1** there is a new **"Split to Instances"** node for exactly this purpose:

[image]

The result:
[image]

In **Blender 4.0** you can use the **repeat zone** to split geometry into a lot of instances:
[image]
However, the performance of this solution is worse compared to the "Split to Instances" node of Blender 4.1

Answer (score 4):

Obviously the use case matters for what method to use. But the most practical is to store the group as an attribute on each point.

Here we have 2000 points. We simply group them by 8.We then use the group ID for different functions.

[image]

In this case we simply randomly move the groups around

[image]

Comment: Interesting! Thank you! For translating groups of points this works great. However I don't think I could easily apply rotation to a group of points. That would be a lot easier if each group of points could be converted to an instance.

Comment: Ah, I understand what you mean now. I think your repeat zone idea might be the best option. I'll see if there's another way tomorrow without the repeat zone.

Comment: as Hulifier mentioned in a comment above there is a "Split to Instances" node for exactly this purpose, coming up in Blender 4.1. So it is probably not worth the effort to work on other solutions. Thanks though!